# Proof for probability measure

Tags: probability-theory

I would like to have my solution checked.

> Assume $\Omega \neq \emptyset$ is a set and $\Delta$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. Let $w_0 \in \Omega$ be fixed. For $E \in \Delta$, define
>
> $\Delta_{w_0}(E) := 1$ for $w_0 \in E$, otherwise $0$.
>
> Show that $\Delta_{w_0}$ defines a probability measure.

First, we have to show that $\Delta_{w_0}(\Omega) = 1$. This is obviously true since $\Omega$ contains $w_0$.

Next, we have to show the identity

$P(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(E_n)$

for disjoint sets $E_n$.

Let us first assume that there is no $E_n$ that contains $w_0$. That means that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ doesn't contain $w_0$, and therefore we get $P(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) = 0$. Of course the right side equals $0$ too.

Now, let us assume that there is a $E_n$ that contains $w_0$. For the left side, that means that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ contains $w_0$ exactly once. This is the same for the right side since all of the subsets are disjoint to each other, meaning that from the very start, there is exactly one subset that contains $w_0$. Therefore, both sides equal $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof that $ \Delta_{w_0}$ defines a probability measure is correct.